# What is this sanding disc and where could I find one?

Tags: repair, tools, masonry, sanding

As best I can tell, it's a 5" diameter, open-coat, all-metal (steel? tin?) arbor-mounted sanding disc.

It's the only thing that will remove tar from brick on my house, and I really need to purchase more. No idea where this one came from.

[image: front]

[image: back]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks exactly like a Porter Cable paint remover disk, at a glance. 24, 36 or 48 grit, $20 bucks or so.

[image: Disc]

The tool it's made for: the Porter-cable 7403 abrasive paint remover. There probably is a backing pad that supports the disc.

[image: 7403 paint remover]

Here's the pad:
[image: Backing pad]

Not affiliated, don't own one, do own some other Porter-Cable tools, happened to notice these discs when looking for some sanding supplies once.

Comment: Seems like a match. So do the tabs in the arbor hole get pinched by the mounting bolt to retain the cover?

Comment: I think the "tabs" are only tabs from lots of wear and tear - the surface on the "new" picture is a smooth cone, and that is clamped by a cone-washer. Could be it's merely similar, as I guess this is a 6" disk and the question does say 5"...

Comment: Thanks guys. Looks like a tungsten carbide disc is what I'm looking for. Mine is a 5" that looks like a thinner version of the Porter Cable. It was on a rubber backing plater for a drill.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like a wrapper for something that had a solid inner component. You can probably find something with a more solid backing plate, like [this one](http://www.toolstation.com/shop/Power+Tool+Accessories/d80/Grinding+Discs/sd1770/Tungsten+Carbide+Grinding+Disc/p48626) (example only), with tungsten or diamond granules.